# Скрытое сообщение от бота

Tags: python, discord, бот

Использую discord.py и хочу узнать, как сделать такое сообщение:
[image: скрытое сообщение]

Это возможно? Как? В документации не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashContext, SlashCommand

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=discord.Intents.all(), description="Hello")
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)


@slash.slash(
    name="hello",
    description="hello",
    guild_ids=[123]
)
async def _remove_wallet(ctx: SlashContext):
    return await ctx.reply("Hello", hidden=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Это называется эфемеральное сообщение, чтобы его сделать надо в параметр отправки Сообщения указывать параметр `ephemeral=True`

P.S этот параметр можно указывать в ответ на взаимодействие с кнопками/select&context menu и slash коммандами